# Рисовальщик для JTable

Tags: jtable, цвета, java

Есть JTable 1 столбец boolean, 1 Date и несколько String. Написал рендерер - String раскрашен, а boolean и Date нет.

Вот код:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;

/**
 *
 * @author ssi
 */
public class Celrend extends JLabel implements TableCellRenderer{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 900550195481093674L;
    Font f = new Font("Verdana", Font.ITALIC, 14);

    @Override
         public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        JLabel component = new JLabel(value.toString());
        component.setFont(table.getFont());
            if(column==0){component.setOpaque(true);component.setText(Integer.toString(row));component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);}
            if(column==1){component.setOpaque(true);component.setForeground(Color.RED);component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);}
            if(column==3){component.setOpaque(true);component.setForeground(Color.RED);component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);}
            if(column==13){component.setOpaque(true);component.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);}
           if(table.getValueAt(row, 11).equals("-")){ component.setOpaque(true);component.setFont(f);component.setBackground(Color.WHITE);  }

           if(isSelected){ 
            component.setOpaque(true);     
            component.setBackground(new Color(249, 249, 196));  
//            component.setForeground(Color.BLUE);  
        }   
          if(hasFocus){ 
            component.setOpaque(true);     
            component.setBackground(new Color(196, 249, 205));  
//            component.setForeground(Color.BLUE);  
        }  
        return component;
    }
}
```

Подскажите, что не так делаю.